# Overview of browser layout logic

Tags: css, browser, css-float

I'm trying to understand very basic browser layout logic, but I'm having trouble putting together something that is accurate even at a very high level, just describing inline elements, block elements and floats. I see phrases used in several articles like 'normal flow' without defining these terms. So I've taken a stab at a very short, incomplete account of the layout logic. Can someone confirm if it is correct, or if there are errors even at this high level? Thanks for your help!

1. Get the next html element.
2. If it is an inline element, go to 3. If a block element, go to 4.
3. Add the inline element to the current inline element stack. If the stack overflows the available horizontal space, write out a line. Go to 1.
4. If the element is floated, go to 5, otherwise go to 6.
5. If floated left, add to the left float stack. If floated right, add to the right float stack. Go to 1.
6. Write out the left float stack, the inline element stack and the right float stack and start a new line. Write out the block element with a new line at the end. Go to 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not mention `position` in your list, which is important.

I think this [part of the w3 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/visuren.html#dis-pos-flo) should help you. But you might want to start at the [beginning](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/visuren.html#normal-flow).